# Publish event to RabbitMQ when data get expiration time

Tags: events, architecture, rabbitmq, microservices

I am currently on an event driven architecture. We have some data which has an expiration time on our data base. what is  the best solution to publish an event(data-expired) just in the exact moment when that data get expiration time? I would like to do that in real time a not doing an scheduler process or batch.

Comment: I am not able to get expiration time. Can you explain with example ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but as far as I can understand, you can store the expiration datetime and then write a program to fire an event if the datetime.now match that expiration time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to achieve that you will need the DB to have some mechanism to support that. And I can't think of any right now (even less without knowing which DB).

But from the top of my head, I can say: if that expiration date is never modified after being inserted in DB, you could just insert a message in RabbitMQ at the same moment that you insert the data in DB. You would set a TTL in the message, and configure dead lettering in that queue. That way, when the message expires it gets automatically published to another exchange.

You can read more here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

Comment: Thanks Lucas, This is brilliant. This is exacly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure about this solution because I have to check an status before take the decission but I will take it after consuming the new exchange.

Comment: Glad to help :) Just be careful with the caveats listed here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html, you could have some issues if you are mixing messages with different TTLs in the same queue (although the doc is not completely clear). To avoid this I created different queues for each different TTL (because I only have a couple), but maybe it's not a solution for you.